# Change Android's "Make password visible" setting programmatically

Tags: android, passwords, android-settings

I'm trying to change the value of "Make passwords visible" to true programmatically in
Android Settings -> Security -> Passwords-> Make passwords visible.

```
Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.PutInt(Application.Context.ContentResolver,  Settings.Secure.NameOfMissingConstant, 1);
```

I can't seem to find the required constant for this option in `Settings.Secure`.

Answer (score 1):

The constant is [`android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System#TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD).

This is the full code to change the value:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD, 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public void onCheckBox(View v2)
{
 CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.pass_Check);
 EditText et1=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edt_Pass);
    if(cb.isChecked())
    {
    et1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
    }
    else 
    {
    et1.setInputType(129);
    }

 }
```

or

```
 public void onCheckBox(View v2)
 {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)this.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean     b) {
            if(!b)
            {
                    password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
            else
            {
                password.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });

}
```